# How to communicate between two android device connected to same network but without having internet access

Tags: android

I have scenario where i can communicate between two android phone or broadcast something which will listen by other android phone present in same network but without having internet access. Is it possible to do in android just like bluetooth data transfer .

Comment: Please be more specific for what you mean by communication? You want to send a file via wi-fi without a router? or with a router that is not connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible you can achieve this by two way .

1) NSD (Network Service Discovery) :- NSD allow users to identify other devices on the local network that support the services your app requests. Using nsd service you can discover the peer on register on same network. for nsd you can follow below link
[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html)

2) Wifi direct :- The Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P) APIs allow applications to connect to nearby devices without needing to connect to a network or hotspot .
Some feature given below:-

Wi-Fi Direct supports WPA2 encryption. (Some ad-hoc networks support only WEP encryption.)

Devices can broadcast the services that they provide, which helps other devices discover suitable peers more easily.

When determining which device should be the group owner for the network, Wi-Fi Direct examines each device's power management, UI, and service capabilities and uses this information to choose the device that can handle server responsibilities most effectively.

link below for wifi direct [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html)

So you can use both framework for network discovery and after that for sending file use java socket .

Make Socket server and other client socket connect them using ip found by nsd or wifi direct and after that you can broadcast.

Comment: does this socket servers need internet to transfer the data

Comment: no internet only you should be on same wifi that all

Comment: Is NSD working anymore? I'm testing NSDChat project and i can't get my devices to discover any services but its own...

Comment: I havn't check that but its was working last time